# Is it possible to pass a set of values to a variadic template declaration similar to how the fibonacci series is solved

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am looking for a solution with templates which allows me to pass values as template parameters just like its done by specializing templates with particular data types. For ex.

```
template <std::string... Args>
struct MOptional
{
    MOptional()
    {
        possibilities.push_back(std::forward(Args)...);
    }

    std::vector<std::string> possibilities;
};
```

The way I want to use it is something like this.

```
MOptional<"string1", "string2", "string3"> optional;
```

and so the possibilities field in the class should get auto populated with string1,string2 and string3. I know I could do it with a constructor but I am looking for something like the above. I would like the number of strings to be variable.

Obviously this code doesn't compile but just to convey how I want it...

Any Ideas ?

**Final Solution (By Barry with edits)**

```
template <typename T, T... Args>
struct MOptional
{
    MOptional()
    {
        // enum { N = sizeof...(Args) };
        T arr[] = { Args... };
        possibilities.assign(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
    }

    std::vector<T> possibilities;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `string` template arguments, but you can do what you want with any type that you *can* have as template non-type arguments:

```
template <typename T, T... Args>
struct MOptional
{
    MOptional()
    : possibilities{Args...}
    { }

    std::vector<T> possibilities;
};
```

For example, `int`s:

```
MOptional<int, 1, 2, 3> mo;
std::cout << mo.possibilities.size(); // prints 3
```

---

Since MSVC is a little behind on variadic template support, the following can be done instead:

```
MOptional() {
    T arr[] = {Args...};
    possibilities.assign(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This however doesn't compile on visual studio. 1>c:\dev\templatestest\templatestest\templates.h(38): error C2797: 'MOptional<int,1,2,3>::possibilities': list initialization inside member initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not implemented
1>          while compiling class template member function 'MOptional<int,1,2,3>::MOptional(void)'
1>          see reference to function template instantiation 'MOptional<int,1,2,3>::MOptional(void)' being compiled
1>          see reference to class template instantiation 'MOptional<int,1,2,3>' being compiled

Comment: @ssarangi Sorry MSVC isn't up to par :( Can you try something like `T arr[] = {Args...}; possibilities.assign(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));`?

Comment: Any possibility of this working with some form of strings. I am trying const char* but that isn't working either.

Comment: @ssarangi You can have `const char*` non-type template arguments, but they cannot be string literals. You'd have to assign the string literals to a non-local `const char[]` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use strings or other objects as template arguments. What I have done with success though is to use a constexpr hash of a c-string. Here is what that looks like:

```
/**
* @brief Hashes a given c-string using the FNV-1a standard hash.
* @details This is used eg. to use strings as template arguments.
*/
constexpr uint64_t template_hash(const char* x) {
    return *x ? (uint64_t(*x) ^ template_hash(x+1))*1099511628211ul : 14695981039346656037ul;
}

template<uint64_t hash> struct foo { static uint64_t bar() { return hash;} };

int main() {
    std::cout << foo<template_hash("test")>::bar() << std::endl;
}
```

should work just fine. Obviously this does not allow you to retrieve the strings, but you can differentiate the classes based on the string. By modifying the hash you could encode a 8-10 letter string within the template argument, but for more you will have to put some work in...
In case you really need the 8-character version:

```
constexpr uint64_t template_string(const char* x) {
    return *x ? (uint64_t(*x) | (template_string(x+1)<<8)) : 0ul;
}
```

I'll leave it to you to decode that string.